# How to add a custom DQL function in Doctrine 2 using Zend Framework 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, dql

Well the question pretty much lies in the title. I've read the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language) and what I can't find out is how to register the function to my ORM Configuration.

Any help here? Thanks!

Edit: Okay I've done it as Sam said, and made my own class and registered it like

```
            'numeric_functions' => array(
                'LOG10'  => 'Admin\Model\Log10',
            ),
```

However it can't find the class and gives the error

> Class 'Admin\Model\Log10' not found in C:\webserver\apache\htdocs\test\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser.php on line 3322

Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: I think all you need is documented here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html

Comment: Yes that's the doc, I have it linked in the post as well, however I need to make it work in ZF2, and I can't find how to register the function in the config, as I'm saying in my post.

Comment: I've seen the docs so many times, but still not enough I guess.. thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually the link that @foozy gave you is all that you'd need. You simply extend your `doctrine` configuration array:

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection'    => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                // Foo
            )
        ),
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'numeric_functions' => array(
                    'MD5'  => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Md5'
                ),
                'datetime_functions' => array(),
                'string_functions'   => array(),
                'metadata_cache'     => 'filesystem',
                'query_cache'        => 'filesystem',
                'result_cache'       => 'filesystem',
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Ty very much, if you can check my edit on the original post :)

Comment: @Systemfreak Sounds like an autoloading issue. Can you access the class from any controller directly?

Comment: Ugh, I had a typo in the class name as it seemed. Btw you seem to know some stuff on ZF2, would it be inconvenient to ask you if I have any other issue? :)

Comment: @Systemfreak short answer: yes ;) Just post issues here on StackOverflow and you'll find the help you need. If i feel like helping, you'll get my reply anyways...

Answer (score 0):

The error is connected to DoctrineExtensions autoload. For me both solutions from [How to implement beberlei doctrine extensions in zend framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117061/how-to-implement-beberlei-doctrine-extensions-in-zend-framework-2) (manual injection of custom functions and applying via config) worked.