# beberlei/DoctrineExtensions fatal error with zend2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine-extensions

i used  beberlei doctrine extensions in zend framework 2  for mysql GroupConcat after installing it with composer i changed my settings like this from question :

[How to implement beberlei doctrine extensions in zend framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117061/how-to-implement-beberlei-doctrine-extensions-in-zend-framework-2)

```
 'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'string_functions' => array(
               'GroupConcat' => 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat'
            )
        )
    ),
```

**in my local pc everything is ok** but when i upload my code on **my remote server** show this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\MySql\GroupConcat' not found in **/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php on line 3389
```

i updated every thing the code is same i installed composer using composer install and update everything on my remote server i sure the code is same and composer installed every thing

Comment: Looks like you have either forgotten to install the package, or something is borked with your autoloading. Have you added the package to the requirements in your composer.json and run `composer update`?

Comment: @lxg yes i added it to composer.json and run composer update, the folder of it exists in vendor

Comment: Do you use a class loader cache or an optimized autoloader? In that case, try clearing the cache (`app/console cache:clear`) and/or restarting the webserver (or PHP-FPM, whichever you're using).